# Left hand and right hand limits

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

what are the answers of these two limits?
$$\lim_{x\to h^+}c_1\cos(x-a)+c_2\sin (x-a)  $$
$$\lim_{x\to h^-}c_1\cos(x-a)+c_2\sin (x-a)  $$

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They should both be

$$c_1\cos(h-a)+c_2\sin (h-a)  $$

as both $\cos$ and $\sin$ are continuous functions